# Converting RAW JDBC code to use JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have recently started my first Software Dev job out of university and one of my tasks at the moment is to convert raw JDBC Code to use JdbcTemplate in order to get rid of boilerplate code.

I have written an example of a DAO class using JdbcTemplate which retrieves a users address.

Would someone be able to tell me if this looks like the right pattern/approach... or am I
missing anything here ?

```
public class accountsDAO extends StoredProcedure {

  private static final STOREDPROC = "accounts.getAccountDetails";

  public accountsDAO() {
    super(jdbcTemplate,STOREDPROC)
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("client_id"), OracleTypes.VARCHAR, );
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("accounts_csr"), OracleTypes.CURSOR,new AccountAddressExtractor());
    setFunction(false)
    complie()
  }

  private List<String> getAccountAddress(String account) {
     Map<String,Object> params  = new HashMap<String,Object>;
     Map<String,Object results; 
     List<String> data = new  LinkedList<String>();
     try{
       params.put("client_id",account);
       results = execute(params);
       data = (List<String) results.get(0);
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // report error
     }
     return data;
  }

  private class AccountAddressExtractor implements RowMapper<List<String>> {
   @Override
   public List<String> mapRow(Resultset rs, int i) throws SQLException{
       List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
       data.add(rs.getString(1));
       data.add(rs.geString(2));
       data.add(rs.getString(3));

       return data;
   }
  } 

}
```

Comment: Too much data is missing from the question. What is that `StoredProcedure` class you're extending? Where is `declareParameter()` and `setFunction()` methods defined? And I don't see you using `jdbcTemplate` anywhere..

Comment: I'm sorrry... JbdTemplate was the wrong term to use.. I am extending the spring StoredProcedure class: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html. The jdbcTemplate is passed in as a parameter: super(JdbcTemple jdbcTemple, STOREDPROC) but this is the only place it is used.